# How to get My Location in Google Maps with MapsGL enabled?

Tags: google-maps

I've searched around but didn't find an answer so this might not be solvable currently. When MapsGL is enabled, the button to get My Location is nowhere to be found:

[image] [image]

```
  Regular       MapsGL
```

So where is that button with the dot or is the feature not available in the webGL version?

Comment: Try "Get directions"—it might work as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment by the Google Maps Team to [one of their posts on G+](https://plus.google.com/111401917971052287374/posts/bhYnN1QvZHD):

> Location services ("My Location") works a little differently in MapsGL right now but you can still use it. If you're getting directions, you can still use "My Location" as a starting/destination point. Your browser should ask you if you'd like to use a "rough estimate", which is usually pretty accurate. Try this out in Chrome and see if it works for you. You don't need to pick between MapsGL and the "My Location" feature! For anyone else interested, I'm referencing this feature announced a few weeks ago -- http://goo.gl/OJoEK

Answer (score 0):

I like finding my location not just for directions, but to look stuff around where I live.
One solution I found was to type `my location` in the search box. I takes you to your location.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It took me to Vietnam, which is several 1000 miles away from me.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting

```
javascript:void (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(b){var a=document.forms[0],d=b.coords;a.q.value=d.latitude+","+d.longitude;a.submit()})());
```

into the address bar of a modern browser should work…

Credits http://twitter.com/stoyanstefanov/status/289842772335284224